# How to make XPath Search in Div with <b> working?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I am trying to search following text in HTML.

```
The file <b> abc.txt </b> is not available.
```

I have following xpath I am using

```
//div[contains(string(),'The file <b> abc.txt </b> is not available')]
```

But this is not working. If I use the following Xpath , it works though.

```
//div[contains(string(),'is not available')]
```

As I want to search for full text, please suggest how to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<b>...</b>` is not a part of string representation, but child node of `div`. Try below XPath to match required `div` node:

```
//div[.="The file  abc.txt  is not available." and b="abc.txt"]
```

If it doesn't matter whether `"abc.txt"` is bold text, you can simplify to just

```
//div[.="The file  abc.txt  is not available."]
```

If `"The file  abc.txt  is not available."` is just a part of `div` text:

```
//div[contains(., "The file  abc.txt  is not available.")]
```

Comment: Thanks @andersson, It was really helpful.

Comment: You are awesome in the way you write xpath, I learnt a lot from you for xpath writing. Keep positing, I will keep reading your post, thanks.